# In AEM query builder order by based on someproperty=somevalue

Tags: java, adobe, aem, query-builder

I m trying to sort the AEM query builder search results based on particular value of particular property. as we have in any database like MySQL we can sort based on column's value as well (for exp. ORDER BY FIELD('columnName','anyColumnName'). can we have something like this in AEM.

Suppose we have 5 Assets under path /content/dam/Assets.

Asset Name------------dc:title

1.jpg------------------Apple

2.jpg------------------Cat

3.jpg------------------Cat

4.jpg------------------Ball

5.jpg------------------Drag

I need assets on top of the results where **dc:title =** **cat** and also need other results also in sorting asc. expected result as given below

2.jpg------------------Cat

3.jpg------------------Cat

1.jpg------------------Apple

4.jpg------------------Ball

5.jpg------------------Drag

Note:- Using version AEM 6.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `orderby` predicate with a value of `@jcr:content/metadata/dc:title` to sort by `dc:title` with the [QueryBuilder](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/QueryBuilder.html). `/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html` is an interface to test queries on your instance. [ACS Commons](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/search/querybuilder/impl/SampleQueryBuilder.java) has a good breakdown of all out of the box predicates

If you want to pull Cats to the top of the results with a single query, you could write a custom predicate. The sample code from ACS Commons shows an example. Adobe has [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/search/implementing-custom-predicate-evaluator.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks @bfitzpatrick ....can you please put more light on custom predicate in which i can order the dc:title based on value